# The uiwebview is not redirected the URL

Tags: ios, redirect, uiwebview

I'm using the uiwebview to link to an URL.
When I use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlPath]];
```

It's worked ok. But I want to use a webview for running in app, so I use:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlPath]];
 [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
 [request addValue:@"YES" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Mobile-App"];
 [_webView loadRequest:request];
```

and it's not worked.
I logged on the code in the method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

In the first time, the URL is: "www.xxx.com/.../redirect/..." and it's the correct link I need to link. But when it's still loading the link, in the second time, the URL that's logged is just: "www.xxx.com/" just is the home page URL of website. Then it's stopped the loading process, so it can not link to the site I want.
I've searched so many results on the web but it's not helped.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added webview programatically or in storyboard?

Comment: Thank you, I did, it opened the webview but showed the home page, not the page I want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

I used NSURLConnection follow the question: 
[UIWebView does not load HTTPS Page: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121767/uiwebview-does-not-load-https-page-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-999-the)
and It's worked.
Thanks :D